# Extract from a song. Meaning of "Wird schon gehen"

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

These are the first lines of a song by AnnenMayKantereit , the song is called "3. Stock".

> Immer wieder schön, dich wieder zu sehen
>   Wird Immer schlimmer, wenn du gehst
>   Am Bahnhof stehst, um den Zug zu nehmen
>   Sich lang' nicht wiedersehen.
>   Wird schon irgendwie gehen,
>   macht manchmal traurig

I can understand the first three lines but I'm having a hard time trying to give meaning to the last three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Wird schon gehen" = "I will handle my situation somehow".

This implies: I catched from a glimpse up to full extent the future consequences and activities due to the result of current decision.

When it is clear to me what will follow, I might not tell you because

- it might burden you (emotionally) which I don't want now.
- you might not understand it/takes unwillingly amount of time to explain it now.

When it is unclear to me what will follow, I might not tell you because

- what comes into my mind as idea is to blurry
- I might fear the (near) future and I don't want to tell you (as the listener) these for various reasons: You might not understand them/they might burden you emotionally [like in the song]
- when I (as the speaker) have no clue what to do and I know I have/will follow the duty/task to keep it going (without you (as the listener))

These instant ideas about future can be neutral - just there is at least an idea/foreshadow of it.
More usual is to think of a future that requires something to do from me I don't like to do. So somewhat negative with a wide range of negative and a wide range of doing.

The last three lines are talking about the topic/conclusion of first three lines:

- First three lines say "nice to see you - and each time you go - your departure gets emotional worse for me".
- Thus last three lines talk about "to not see each other for a long time - I will manage it without telling you now what I fear it will be for me - and sometimes it makes me sad".

Comment: Thanks Shegit! Very helpful indeed. Now I understand the whole paragraph. Nice! thanks a lot for your time!!

Comment: as far I understand SE it’s use to give an upvote for saying thank you :)

Comment: Hi Albrecht! I'm new here. What do you mean by SE?

Comment: @Joe: SE = StackExchange = this platform you posted your question. Upvote give reputation = rights to do some things, see https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges for details. (SE started with SO = StackOverflow and got many subsites since). So I say verbally thank you for picking my answer ;-)

Answer (score 5):

> Wird schon irgendwie gehen

means

> It'll be all right (somehow)

Based on:
[Discussion about translation of "Es wird schon gehen"](https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=692240)

Answer (score 2):

**In poetry it is possible to let drop a pronoun - just as in everyday language.**

> Wird schon gehen

is actually the future tense  of: Es geht.

*Wie gehts? - Es geht!* (wie geht **es**? = wie geht’**s**?)

if you let drop the pronoun: (es) wird schon gehen.

(**es**) macht manchmal traurig, sich lang nicht wiedersehen.

(**It** makes me sad not seeing you for a long time.)

In the last line **es** would replace the missing  **this**

Comment: Do you think that this is more or less specific for "wird schon gehen"? In my opinion that is very common, at least in poetry because rhyme schemes request to drop syllables from time to time. And I miss the explanation of "es" as I find understanding of "es" relevant to current question.

Comment: Edited! I don’t think the pronoun **es**  in **es geht** needs any further explanation as this is the answer to “hallo, wie gehts?* and one of the first terms a foreigner will learn ... and especially not to someone who says that he understand the first 3 lines of the song. Yes, this is very specific. In any case more than “I will make it” as it explains the root or the origine of this term. It will be more difficult for somoene who Is learning our  language and our grammar to understand the concept of future and missing words in poetry

Answer (score 1):

"Wird schon irgendwie gehen"
Imagine your car is about to break down, but nobody can tell you exactly how many miles the car will last. You want to drive a long long journey with this car. And lets imagine you get asked "what will you do when your car break down, far away from home?". And you dont have a clue, but you know it will "work out somehow". Then (in german) you say "Wird schon irgendwie gehen"

Sorry for my English! Im a native german speaker and my english is not the best.